# How to scrape data

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am trying scrape data from this url: http://icecat.biz/en/p/Coby/DP102/desc.htm

I want to scrape that **specs** table from that url.

But I checked source code of url that spec table is not displaying because i think that table is loading using Ajax.

How can I get that table.Whats needs to be done?

I used the following code:

```
string Strproducturl = "http://icecat.biz/en/p/Coby/DP102/desc.htm";
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Strproducturl);
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: My first guess here would be that you need to make the ajax calls, you might get json back which would be easier than web-scraping

Comment: The ajax call for the data tables seem to be urls like: http://icecat.biz/index.cgi?ajax=productPage;product_id=1091664;language=en;request=feature

Comment: but allthis process is automated.I gave you that url for just for an example.I have checked reponse also but that specs table source is coming in that response.

Answer (score 1):

As IanNorton mentioned, you'll need to make your request to the URL that Icecat use to load the specs using AJAX. For the example link you provided, the specs details URL you'll need to request will be:

http://icecat.biz/index.cgi?ajax=productPage;product_id=1091664;language=en;request=feature

You can then work your way through the HTML response to get the spec details you require.

You mentioned in your comment that the scraping process is automated. The specs URL is in a basic format, you just need the product ID. However, if you don't have the IDs, just a series of URLs like the example on in your original question, you'll need to get the product ID from the URL you have.

For example, the URL example you gave redirects to a different URL:

http://icecat.biz/p/coby/dp102/digital-photo-frames-0716829961025-dp-102-digital-photo-frame-1091664.html

This URL contains the product ID, right at the end.

You could do a `HttpWebRequest` to your original URL, stop before it does the redirect and catch the redirecting URL:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://icecat.biz/en/p/Coby/DP102/desc.htm");
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.KeepAlive = true;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect){

    string redirectUrl = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");

}
```

Once you've got the `redirectUrl` variable, you can use `Regex` to get the ID then do another `HttpWebRequest` to the specs detail URL.

Comment: string redirectUrl = response.GetResponseHeader("Location"); 

Location means exactly what? I mean what I need to be enter there?

Can you please help?

Comment: The value of `redirectUrl` will be the URL that your example URL is redirecting to, the one that contains the product ID: http://icecat.biz/p/coby/dp102/digital-photo-frames-0716829961025-dp-102-digital-photo-frame-1091664.html Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a library like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to select various elements from the html document.

I took a quick look at the link and noticed that the data is actually loaded using an addtional ajax request. You can use the following url to get the ajax data

http://icecat.biz/index.cgi?ajax=productPage;product_id=1091664;language=en;request=feature

The use HtmlAgilityPack to parse that data.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but you could more easily just retrieve the XML from

https://openIcecat-xml:freeaccess@data.icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/EN/1091664.xml

You will also get all images and descriptions as well :-)